# LocalDateTime.parse() with format that doesn't have hour, minute etc

Tags: java, datetime

I want to parse a date-time string to LocalDateTime. The input format may not contain hour, minute etc fields. For example it can be "yyyy M d". Given this pattern you can parse a string to a LocalDate, but not LocalDateTime. I want to create LocalDateTime.

There is a way to do this with DateTimeFormatterBuilder as shown below.

```
// this code works. But I don't want to use DateTimeFormatterBuilder
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("yyyy")
                .appendLiteral('-')
                .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR)
                .appendLiteral('-')
                .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH)
                .parseDefaulting(HOUR_OF_DAY, 12)
                .parseDefaulting(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 13)
                .parseDefaulting(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 14)
                .toFormatter();
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-09-05", formatter));
```

But I want to use DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern() instead of DateTimeFormatterBuilder. But I don't know how to make the below code work:

```
// this code doesn't work.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-d");
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-09-05", formatter));
```

It throws the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-09-05' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2015-09-05 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
...
```

Comment: `ofPattern` cannot do everything the builder can do... "I want to use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`". **Don't.** Patterns are crap. The builder is much easier to read, even if it is quite verbose.

Comment: @Thomas He knows that.

Comment: Why don't you use the builder and pass the entire pattern via `.appendPattern("yyyy-M-d")`? That way you could set the defaults as well.

Comment: @Thomas, yes, I missed that part. Silly me! Thanks for pointing out.